# org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement OAuth in my spring boot rest server. [Here's my configurations](https://gist.github.com/freddy-daniel/2bb84c2da5b50f16ec45c4b5b486ea5d)

configuration\AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```java
package com.vcomm.server.configuration;

import com.vcomm.server.service.util.CustomAuthenticationKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Resource(name = "roomUserDetailsService")
  UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    JdbcTokenStore tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    tokenStore.setAuthenticationKeyGenerator(new CustomAuthenticationKeyGenerator());
    return tokenStore;
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey("123");
    return converter;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    defaultTokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return defaultTokenServices;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource);
  }

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
      .pathMapping("/oauth/authorize", Constant.AUTH_V1 + "/oauth/authorize")
      .pathMapping("/oauth/check_token", Constant.AUTH_V1 + "/oauth/check_token")
      .pathMapping("/oauth/confirm_access", Constant.AUTH_V1 + "/auth/v1/oauth/confirm_access")
      .pathMapping("/oauth/error", Constant.AUTH_V1 + "/oauth/error")
      .pathMapping("/oauth/token", Constant.AUTH_V1 + "/oauth/token")
      .pathMapping("/oauth/token_key", Constant.AUTH_V1 + "/oauth/token_key")
      .tokenStore(tokenStore())
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
      .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  }

  @EventListener
  public void authSuccessEventListener(AuthenticationSuccessEvent authorizedEvent){
    // write custom code here for login success audit
    System.out.println("User Oauth2 login success");
    System.out.println("This is success event : "+authorizedEvent.getSource());
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer
      .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
      .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
  }
}
```

configuration\ResourceServerConfig.java

```java
package com.vcomm.server.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
      .antMatcher("/api/**")
      .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
      .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
  }

  @Autowired
  TokenStore tokenStore;

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
    config.tokenServices(tokenServicesResourceServer());
  }

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Bean
  public DefaultTokenServices tokenServicesResourceServer() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    defaultTokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return defaultTokenServices;
  }

}
```

configuration\SpringWebSecurityConfig.java

```java
package com.vcomm.server.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Configuration
  @Order(1001)
  public static class superAdminWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "emUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService emUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
              .sessionManagement()
              .maximumSessions(2)
              .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);

      http
              .csrf().disable();
      http
              .httpBasic()
              .disable();

      http
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/superadmin/api/v1/login")
              .permitAll();

      http
              .logout()
              .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/superadmin/api/v1/logout", "POST"))
              .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
              .logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT))
              .invalidateHttpSession(true);

      http
              .antMatcher("/superadmin/**")
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/superadmin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN_PRIVILEGE");

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
      return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean(name = "emAuthenticationProvider")
    public AuthenticationProvider emAuthenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
      provider.setUserDetailsService(emUserDetailsService);
      return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(emUserDetailsService);
      auth.authenticationProvider(emAuthenticationProvider());
    }

  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(1002)
  public static class adminWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
              .sessionManagement()
              .maximumSessions(2)
              .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);

      http
              .csrf().disable();
      http
              .httpBasic()
              .disable();

      http
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/admin/api/v1/login")
              .permitAll();

      http
              .logout()
              .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/api/v1/logout", "POST"))
              .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
              .logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT))
              .invalidateHttpSession(true);

      http
              .antMatcher("/admin/**")
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ORGANISATION_PRIVILEGE");
    }


  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(1003)
  public static class appWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Resource(name = "roomUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService roomUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
              .sessionManagement()
              .maximumSessions(2)
              .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);

      http
              .csrf().disable();
      http
              .httpBasic()
              .disable();

      http
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/api/v1/*/login")
              .permitAll();

      http
              .logout()
              .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/logout", "POST"))
              .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
              .logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT))
              .invalidateHttpSession(true);

      http
              .antMatcher("/api/**")
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROOM_PRIVILEGE");
    }

    @Bean(name = "roomPasswordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder roomPasswordEncoder(){
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "roomAuthenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
      return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean(name = "roomAuthenticationProvider")
    public AuthenticationProvider roomAuthenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      provider.setPasswordEncoder(roomPasswordEncoder());
      provider.setUserDetailsService(roomUserDetailsService);
      return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(roomUserDetailsService);
      auth.authenticationProvider(roomAuthenticationProvider());
    }

  }

}
```

While calling `http://localhost:5524/auth/v1/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientapp&response_type=code&scope=read` 
I got this response

```
{
    "timestamp": 1582545217836,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/auth/v1/oauth/authorize"
}
```

I'm using jdbc to manage state of oauth here's my oauth table data

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| client_id | resource_ids | client_secret | scope | authorized_grant_types                    | web_server_redirect_uri | authorities | access_token_validity | refresh_token_validity |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| clientapp | NULL         | secret        | read  | password,authorization_code,refresh_token | http://localhost:8081/  | room        |                 36000 |                  36000 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

I think [this error log](https://gist.github.com/freddy-daniel/a11697930a8804a8522afec78c5f773f) is enough to answer this question because I'm new to spring boot.
If need additional information please ask through commants

Comment: Please add your configuration to your question, instead of us having to follow links.

Answer (score 0):

It was my misunderstanding OAuth workflow. While calling this URL it's trying to authenticate me before grant. But postman showed just 401 instead of giving a redirect response. Calling it via a browser will redirect me to the login page for authentication.
Posting this answer to help guys new to OAuth and spring boot :)